# Android Sorting data into arrays - ArrayAdapter JSON Listview

Tags: php, android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a MySQL table called foods which contain diet information. I am currently running the php script which calls the following sql command Select * from Food where dietid = 1 which returns the image below.

[image]

The column day is the day of the diet so day 1, day 2 etc.. the time refers to a point during the day so time 1 is breakfast time 2 is snack time 3 is lunch time 4 is afternoon snack and time 5 is dinner.

I would like to display the data in the following way in a listview for each day of the diet.Description is the made out of qty measure and item

[image]

I have the following output in the log-cat at the moment.

## UPDATE - EDIT NEW LOGCAT

Using Jims approact i have been able to group this data by day and time in the format that i require however i am now facing the problem which i was facing before, the list gets inflated and it puts the information in each row when i need it all to be in 1 row per 1 day.

[image]

The problem is that now it inflates the views like this which creates one view and puts it in for each item.

## UPDATED THE ARRAYADAPTER#

[image]

[image]

I would like to group this data in arrays for each day, so it would be day 1 - breakfast - item, snack - item etc... so that i can put it all in one list for the user to view.

All my data is stored in 2 model classes. Below is my adapter with the model classes.

Thanks :) getting there..

## ArrayAdapter Class UPDATED

```
public class DietAdapterNew extends ArrayAdapter<FoodInfoModel>{

private List<FoodInfoModel> items;



private TextView diet_day, breakfast_data, snach1_data, lunch_data, snack2_data, dinner_data ;


private LinearLayout ratingCntr;
private TextView followersText;



public DietAdapterNew(Context context, List<FoodInfoModel> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_diet_single_day);


    this.items = items;

}


public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_diet_single_day, null);            
    }

    FoodInfoModel infomodel = items.get(position);


    if(infomodel != null) {



        diet_day = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.diet_day);
        breakfast_data = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.breakfast_data);
        snach1_data  = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.snack1_data);
        lunch_data = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lunch_data);
        snack2_data = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.snack2_data);
        dinner_data =  (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dinner_data);




              List<DayFoodModel> daylist = new ArrayList<DayFoodModel>();

            DayFoodModel dayfoodmodel = new DayFoodModel();
            dayfoodmodel.setDay(infomodel.getDay());
            dayfoodmodel.setTime(infomodel.getTime());
            dayfoodmodel.setFoodData(infomodel.getItem() + infomodel.getMeasure());

            diet_day.setText("Current day "  );


            Collections.sort(daylist, new DayComparator());
            daylist.add(dayfoodmodel);




            Log.v("Logging", "Info" +  daylist);



        //      };



             if (dayfoodmodel.getTime() == 1 ) {

                  if( breakfast_data != null)  breakfast_data.setText(dayfoodmodel.getFoodData());

             }

             if (dayfoodmodel.getTime() == 2) {

                 if( snach1_data != null)  snach1_data.setText(dayfoodmodel.getFoodData());

         }

             if (dayfoodmodel.getTime() == 3) {

                 if( lunch_data != null)  lunch_data.setText(dayfoodmodel.getFoodData());

         }

             if (dayfoodmodel.getTime() == 4) {

                  if( snack2_data != null)  snack2_data.setText(dayfoodmodel.getFoodData());

         }

             if (dayfoodmodel.getTime() == 5) {

                 if( dinner_data != null)  dinner_data.setText(dayfoodmodel.getFoodData()); 

         }



        //  


         }


//   }

    return v;
}
}
```

## DayFoodModel.java

```
public class DayFoodModel {

int _day;
int _qty;
int _time;
String _item;
String _measure;
String _food_data;




public DayFoodModel()
{

}



public DayFoodModel(int day, int qty, int time,  String item, String measure, String food_data){


    this._day = day;
    this._qty = qty;
    this._item = item;
    this._time = time;
    this._measure = measure;
    this._food_data = food_data;



}

public DayFoodModel(String item, String measure, String food_data)

{
  this._item = item;
  this._measure = measure;
  this._food_data = food_data;

}


public int getDay(){
    return this._day;
}

public void setDay(int day){
    this._day = day;

}

public int getQty(){
    return this._qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty){
    this._qty = qty;

}

public int getTime(){
    return this._time;
}

public void setTime(int time){
    this._time = time;

}

public String getItem(){
    return this._item;
}

public void setItem(String item){
    this._item = item;
}

public String getMeasure(){
    return this._measure;
}

public void setMeasure(String measure){
    this._measure = measure;
}

public String getFoodData(){
    return this._food_data;
}

public void setFoodData(String food_data){
    this._food_data = food_data;
}


}
```

## FoodInfoModel

```
public class FoodInfoModel
    {

int _dietid;
int _id;
int _day;
int _qty;
int _time;
String _item;
String _measure;
public String breakfast_data_string;


public FoodInfoModel()
{

}



    public FoodInfoModel(int dietid, int id, int day, int qty, int time,  String item, String measure){

    this._id = id;
    this._dietid = dietid;
    this._day = day;
    this._qty = qty;
    this._item = item;
    this._measure = measure;

    this.breakfast_data_string = measure + item;


    }

public FoodInfoModel(String item, String measure, String breakfast_data_string)

{
  this._item = item;
  this._measure = measure;
    this.breakfast_data_string = measure + item;

}



public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;

}

public int getDietID(){
    return this._dietid;
}

public void setDietID(int dietid){
    this._dietid = dietid;

}

public int getDay(){
    return this._day;
}

public void setDay(int day){
    this._day = day;

}

public int getQty(){
    return this._qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty){
    this._qty = qty;

}

public int getTime(){
    return this._time;
}

public void setTime(int time){
    this._time = time;

}

public String getItem(){
    return this._item;
}

public void setItem(String item){
    this._item = item;
}

public String getMeasure(){
    return this._measure;
}

public void setMeasure(String measure){
    this._measure = measure;
}

public String getBreakfastData(){
    return this.breakfast_data_string;
}

public void setBreakfastData(String breakfast_data_string){
    this.breakfast_data_string = breakfast_data_string;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a custom `Comparator` to your object, then you can use `Arrays.sort` method to do sorting of whatever kind you like.

Here is one reference on how to make and use a `Comparator`:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/

EDIT:

Besides the sorting, you should probably use an `Adapter` against an existing data set. In other words, these lines in your `Adapter` should not exist:

```
        Collections.sort(daylist, new DayComparator());
        daylist.add(dayfoodmodel);
```

First, you are sorting - **then** adding data. All your data should be in the array, and then sort it.

Second, you should pass all the data into the `Adapter` so the sort should occur **before** you do `getView` in the `Adapter`

Comment: Man thanks for that really appreciate it Jim i think you are onto something there never knew about this compartor interface, will have a play around with it and get back to you, cheers :)

Comment: Jim i was able to sort the data acordingly in the logcat but now i am facing the same trouble that i originally had which is adding this data to the actual listview have a look at the update many thanks for your guidance

Comment: Thanks for all the help Jim i have now been able to fix the problem thanks to your answer. cheers