# how to retrive json data to android xml

Tags: android, mysql, xml, json

I am working on a android project and fallowing the below tutorialhttp://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/

By fallowing the above tutorial I'm able to retrieve the data through `JSON` to an list activity and `php` code is working fine, but the problem lies where  I have made a form where I want to retrieve data to just a simple XML with few simple text view's but I'm unable to alter the code . .
below is the code for retrieving data form `JSON` to list activity..

```html
package com.example.policadda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Mycomplaints extends ListActivity {

 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

 
    private static final String READ_COMPLAINTS_URL = "http://divaexample.honor.es/mycomplaints.php";
    
  
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
 
    


    private JSONArray mComments = null;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   
        setContentView(R.layout.my_complaints);   
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
 
     super.onResume();

     new LoadComments().execute();
    }

 public void addComment(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Mycomplaints.this, Complaints.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

   
 public void updateJSONdata() {

  
     
        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        
 
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMPLAINTS_URL);
        
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Mycomplaints.this);
            String post_username = sp.getString("username", "diva");
    
        try {
              List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
               Log.d("request!", "starting");

        JSONObject json1 = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
          READ_COMPLAINTS_URL, "POST", params);
      
            mComments = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

        
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);


                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String content = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                

          
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
              
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, content);
                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
             
           
                mCommentList.add(map);
                
                
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into our listview
     */
 private void updateList() {
 // hear data has been retrived to and list acitvity
 // But i need title message and username to be retrived to an text view but i am unable to do it
  
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
    R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_SUBJECT,
      TAG_USERNAME }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
      R.id.username });

  setListAdapter(adapter);
  

  ListView lv = getListView(); 
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {

  

   }
  });
 }       

    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

     @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Mycomplaints.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Loading complaints...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
   pDialog.show();
  }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        
           updateJSONdata();

            return null;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            updateList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28345087/4404791

Comment: not clear, do you  expect to convert your response into xml ?